# Regex to replace image tag containing specific occurence?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have below  message String. I want to replace all the image tag  which contains the occurence of sequence i.e  ?custId=1234  with new string cid:

```
 String message = "Need to process  image tag <img src=\"http://danny.oz.au/p/56214815-tripod.jpg?custId=1234\"/>";
```

This what i tried after going thru bit of regex tutorial which replaces all image tag occurence with cid:. **I am not getting how to  fit the
    one more filter i.e ?custId=1234 in regex so that replace only those image tags that contains ?custId=1234**

```
  message = message.replaceAll("\\<img.*?>", "cid:");
```

**EDIT:- For example if
input is**

```
  "Need to process  image tag <img src=\"http://danny.oz.au/p/56214815-tripod.jpg?custId=1234\"/>";
```

**output should be**
       "Need to process  image tag cid:";

becoz input contains img tag and ?custId=1234 both

**input is**

```
     "Need to process  image tag <img src=\"http://danny.oz.au/p/56214815-tripod.jpg?custId=1235\"/>";
```

**output should be**

```
     "Need to process  image tag <img src=\"http://danny.oz.au/p/56214815-tripod.jpg?custId=1235\"/>";
```

becoz input does not contain ?custId=1234 both

Comment: Could you put a real example? I haven't understsood you well

Comment: [Use an XML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/647772)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: -

```
message = message.replaceAll("<img.*?\\?custId=1234.*?>", "cid:");
```

**For your given input string: -**

```
"Need to process  image tag <img src=\"http://danny.oz.au/p/56214815-tripod.jpg?"
+ "custId=1234\"/>"
```

**this will give you: -**

```
"Need to process  image tag cid:"
```

**Also for input**: -

```
"Need to process  image tag <img src=\"http://danny.oz.au/p/56214815-tripod.jpg?custId=1235\"/>"
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
"Need to process  image tag <img src=\"http://danny.oz.au/p/56214815-tripod.jpg?custId=1235\"/>"
```

Also, I would suggest you to take a look at [**`Jsoup - Java HTML Parser`**](http://jsoup.org/), which you should use to parse your HTML. Regex is not a good idea to parse HTML. You can only parse a limited range of tags.

You can also use [**`HTML Cleaner`**](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/)

---

**UPDATE: -**

If you want your `dot (.)` to match `newline` also, you can use `PAttern.DOTALL` flag. Alternativey, in case of `String.replaceAll()`, you can add a `(?s)` at the start of the pattern, which is equivalent to this flag.

From the [`Pattern.DOTALL` - JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) : -

> Dotall mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression (?s).
>   (The s is a mnemonic for "single-line" mode, which is what this is
>   called in Perl.)

So, you can modify your pattern like this: -

```
message = message.replaceAll("(?s)<img.*?\\?custId=1234.*?>", "cid:");
```

Comment: @MSach. You have a wide range of `HTML` tags, with wide range of attributes. By using regex, you cannot parse and get information out of all of them. Also, different tags behave differently, and can be used in a different way. So, you should always use tools, that are specifically made for this purpose. Use a HTML Parser.

Comment: @MSach. Regex are for normal text processing, and not for somthing that follow some order. For E.g, it is very weak at taking care of say `opening` and corresponding `closing` brackets.

Comment: @MSach. I hope you got it. You can take a look at the two links I have provided. :)

Comment: Rohit one more favour. Can You explain the metadat characters you used in between img and custId i.e img.*?\\?custId. how this work. I tried to get their meaning at http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html but could not make out why we used .*?\\? between img and custId

Comment: `.*?` means match everything `reluctant`. `?` is used for reluctant matching. means it will match the least character before the next pattern is matched.  Then we need to match the `?` of `?custId`. For that we need to escape `?` with backslash: - `\\?` because it has special meaning.

Comment: For E.G: -   In the string: - `My name is Rohit. Hello Rohit`.  `.*Rohit` will match every character till the last `Rohit`. Whereas, `.*?Rohit` will only match every characters till the first `Rohit`

Comment: For more on quantifiers: - See [`tutorial`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) and for more on escape characters: - See [`Pattern Docs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: @MSach. Thanks. Glad that I could help you :)

Comment: Rohit one more thing on same regex. I want to check whether any given string contains above regex or not. java string does not have any method contains(Regex regex) . I tried  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\<img.*?\\&attachmentId=1234.*?>",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    String messageBody2 = "  <p>Test Customer</p>  <p><img src=\"getCustomers.do?actionCode=2&attachmentId=1234&pwd=70b73ca82575707e86c417c1644696d&Cli=4db8e459e30760f625487ce13dfaf5a8\" alt=\"\" /></p>";
    boolean test = p.matcher(messageBody2).matches(); but test returns false it should be true

Comment: @MSach. You don't need to escape `&`. Just try: - `Pattern.compile("\\<img.*?&attachmentId=1234.*?>");`

Comment: Rohit found one issue with regex "\\<img.*?\\?custId=1234.*?>". here it is if img tag is constructed in a way so that src="someURL" starts in next line of '<img' then regex "\\<img.*?\\?custId=1234.*?>" does not work.To test out this created the text file with content    
  <img  src="cid:part1.04020903.02030306" alt=""> where src starting in next line of img. Then i read the file with fileReader in to string say contentStr. Then i did contentStr.replaceAll("\\<img.*?cid:part1.04020903.02030306.*?>",
        "abcd"). It does not work 
 "\\<img.*?\\?custId=1234.*?>" ignore end of line character

Comment: But as soon as i remove the end of line character betwwn img and src it works. Is there a way regex
"\\<img.*?\\?custId=1234.*?>"  ignore end of line character in between.

Comment: @MSach.. And you don't need to escape your `<`. I think I mistyped it previously. I have edited that part. You can see the change.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Rohit it worked. You deserve separate answer accepted for this. Posted a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249099/ignoring-the-line-break-in-regex. Please post answer there so that i can accept it

Comment: @MSach.. haha :) You're welcome. But that was not needed, as your problem is already solved. Still I have added it there as an answer. You can only accept it after 15 minutes. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use ths String Contains function to first filter for those that have "custid=".  e.g.

```
if (message.contains("custId=1234") {
    message = message.replaceAll("\\<img.*?>", "cid:");
}
```

Comment: What if message contains both - a tag with `custId=1234` and one without it?

Comment: I didn't get the impression from the example that this was a possability but certainly if it was then my suggestion would need refining to first extract the image tag as a substring and then just perform the test for custId on that string.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got you [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tB6fQ9)

`"Need to process  image tag.*\?custId=(\d+)"`

Here you have a regex that backreferences you your id, then you can print Need to procces the cId: match.group(1) or whatever you need to.