# Ignoring the line break in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have below content in text file

```
  some texting content <img  src="cid:part123" alt=""> <b> Test</b>
```

I read it from file and store it in String i.e inputString

```
   expectedString = inputString.replaceAll("\\<img.*?cid:part123.*?>",
    "NewContent");
```

I get expected output i.e

```
     some texting content NewContent <b> Test</b>
```

Basically if there is end of line character in between img and src like below, it does not work for example below

```
 <img  
          src="cid:part123" alt="">
```

Is there a way regex   ignore end of line character in between while matching?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want your `dot (.)` to match `newline` also, you can use [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag. Alternativey, in case of `String.replaceAll()`, you can add a `(?s)` at the start of the pattern, which is equivalent to this flag.

From the [`Pattern.DOTALL` - JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) : -

> **Dotall** mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression *(?s)*.
>   (The *s* is a mnemonic for "single-line" mode, which is what this is
>   called in Perl.)

So, you can modify your pattern like this: -

```
expectedStr = inputString.replaceAll("(?s)<img.*?cid:part123.*?>", "Content");
```

**NOTE: -** You don't need to escape your `angular bracket(<)`.

Comment: Hey Rohit can you help me for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865750/why-this-regex-not-giving-expected-output. Its a question related to above one only but somehow not getting expected outcome when i have two img tags. See if you can help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

By default, the `.` character will not match newline characters. You can enable this behavior by specifying the [`Pattern.DOTALL` flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL). In `String.replaceAll()`, you do this by attaching a `(?s)` to the front of your pattern:

```
expectedString = inputString.replaceAll("(?s)\\<img.*?cid:part123.*?>", 
    "NewContent");
```

See also [Pattern.DOTALL with String.replaceAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500036/pattern-dotall-with-string-replaceall)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode.

`replaceAll()` doesn't take mode flags as a separate argument, but you can enable them in the expression as follows:

```
expectedString = inputString.replaceAll("(?s)\\<img.*?cid:part123.*?>", ...);
```

Note, however, that it's not a good idea to parse HTML with regular expressions. It would be better to use HTML parser instead.