# Enclose group of line having 4 spaces in the beginning

Tags: java, regex

I want to enclose all the lines in `<pre>` tag that have 4 spaces in the beginning.

What I have tried?

```
^[ ]{4}(.*)(?!=^[ ]{4})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rN2wN9/1)

Input:

```
Here is the code:
    String name = "Jon";
    System.out.println("Hello "+name);
output:
    Hello Jon
```

Actual output:

```
Here is the code: 
    <pre>String name = "Jon";</pre> 
    <pre>System.out.println("Hello "+name);</pre>
output: 
    <pre>Hello Jon</pre>
```

Expected output:

```
Here is the code:
<pre>
    String name = "Jon";
    System.out.println("Hello "+name);
</pre>
output:
<pre>
    Hello Jon
</pre>
```

Java sample code:

```
text.replaceAll(regex, "<pre>$1</pre>");
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: ^(\s){4}(.*)(?!=^(\s){4})....does that work?

Comment: Ignore line breaks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249099/ignoring-the-line-break-in-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
String out = input.replaceAll("(?m)((?:^ {4}\\S.*$\\r?\\n)*^ {4}\\S.*$)", 
                              "<pre>\\n$1\\n</pre>");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rN2wN9/4)

**Explanation:**

```
(?m)                    # enable multilie mode
^ {4}\\S.*$             # match a line with exact 4 spaces at start
\\r?\\n                 # followed by a line feed character
(?:^ {4}\\S.*$\\r?\\n)* # match 0 or more of such lines
^ {4}\\S.*$             # followed by a line with exact 4 spaces at start
<pre>\\n$1\\n</pre>     # replace by <pre> newline matched block newline </pre>
```

Comment: Thank let me try to understand it.

Comment: Added an explanation of regex and of course regex101 demo link also has some details.

Comment: that last part `^ {4}\\S.*$ ` is not understood. Why there is no negative look around? why `^ {4}\\S.*$ ` is needed?

Comment: oh there is no lookahead. Last part is `^ {4}\\S.*$` which is matching last such line **without** a newline so that we can avoid adding 2 newlines before `</pre>` otherwise regex can be simplified to: `(?m)((?:^ {4}\\S.*$\\r?\\n?)+` also.

Comment: Yes you can sure ask as many, I will be offline for couple of hours due to some work but will answer all the queries once I come back online.